# Javscript using await inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a React application that uses the Github API
The below code is expected to return a list that contains the number of commits per repository and store in a state variable called `reposAndCommits` which is initalized to `[]`

```
getCommitsInfo = () => {
        const repos = [...this.state.repos]
        repos.map(async (repo) => {
            await axios.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + this.state.user + '/' + repo + "/commits")
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        reposAndCommits: [...this.state.reposAndCommits, { repo: res.data.length }]
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        })
        console.log(this.state.reposAndCommits)
    }
```

However, the console.log outputs an empty list `[]` and this happens even before the full response is recieved. I have added an `await` but it doesn't work as expected.

I want the `console.log(this.state.reposAndCommits)` to be executed only after the map function is fully completed. I think my placement of await is not accurate and I'm not able to figure out where to place it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For multiple promise request. You need to use `Promise.all` . React more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Array's `.map()` method doesn't wait for async callbacks to complete before starting the next iteration

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Thanks for that. Could you please tell where exactly should I modify my code and add that?

Answer (score 3):

The reason the console.log contains no results is because `.map` isn't an async function. What happens is you are mapping the requests, but these will still be an array of Promises which won't stay in the current lexical scope. To solve this you can make use of `Promise.all`. This will make it so you can wait for an array of promises to complete:

```
getCommitsInfo = async () => {
        const repos = [...this.state.repos]
        // Map the requests, this will be an array of promises
        const requests = repos.map((repo) => {
            axios.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + this.state.user + '/' + repo + "/commits")
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        reposAndCommits: [...this.state.reposAndCommits, { repo: res.data.length }]
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        })
        // Wait till all promises are resolved
        await Promise.all(requests)
        console.log(this.state.reposAndCommits)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although now I seem to have another issue. the `repo` in `{repo: res.data.length}` doesn't seem refer to the map variable and instead all of them are getting stored as plain text like `[{repo: 10},{repo: 12},{repo: 5}...]` Any idea what's causing this bug?

Comment: I think it would be better for the main `.map()` to return the Promise instances from `axios.get()` with no `.then()`. That way the array isn't rebuilt for each response. The `.then()` for the `Promise.all()` can assemble the final array more efficiently from the array of responses (probably via another `.map()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it one way like, push all the `axis.get` promises into an array and then use `Promise.all` on top of that array along with `await`. Once all the promises gets resolved, you can capture the response and update the state accordingly.

````
getCommitsInfo = async() => {
  try {
    const repos = [...this.state.repos];
    const promises = repos.map(repo =>
      axios.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + this.state.user + '/' + repo + "/commits");
    );
    const responseArr = await Promise.all(promises);
    const repoData = responseArr.map((res, i) => ({
      [repos[i]]: res.data
    }));
    this.setState({
      reposAndCommits: [...this.state.reposAndCommits, ...repoData]
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.reposAndCommits)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}```
````

Comment: The `res` from `Promise.all()` is going to be an **array** of responses. This is the right way to do things, but the state needs to be set to a `.map()` from those responses into the desired objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue @Pointy. I have updated my answer.